# Selenium Clicking all follow buttons on instagram Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, instagram

I am trying to automate Instagram follow button clicks when you click on a user's username on the Instagram website.

Upon clicking the username, you then click followers and a window opens containing the people following this person and there are follow buttons

Here's a screenshot of the new window

[image]

I am trying to click the buttons one by one through python selenium but nothing I try seems to work.

The best I got was a for loop that only clicked the first follow button using xpath but the other buttons were not clicked.

```
#click the followers button to dispaly the users followers
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("followers").click()
time.sleep(3)
#scroll through the followers list to a specified heeight
scroll_box=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]")
last_ht, ht=0, 1
while last_ht !=ht:
    last_ht=ht
    time.sleep(2)
    ht=driver.execute_script("""arguments[0].scrollTo(0, 2000);
    return 2000;
    """, scroll_box)
#follow users up to the specified height
follow=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[1]/div/div[3]/button")
for x in range (0,len(follow)):
        follow[x].click()
        time.sleep(2)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Xpath selector seems to be copied straight from the chrome developer tools and BTW it will only return one button as you are targeting one `li`

```
# Get all buttons that has the text Follow 
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Follow')]")
for btn in buttons:
    # Use the Java script to click on follow because after the scroll down the buttons will be un clickeable unless you go to it's location
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What if we have already followed someone and if it asks me this :

[image: unfollow]

and if I want to add `if` statement to this code :

```
#scroll through the followers list to a specified heeight
# Get all buttons that has the text Follow 
buttons = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Follow')]")

for btn in buttons:
    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
    sleep(99)
```

and later on-site started giving this messag[it is blocking my action to click on follow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YszwF.png)e

Answer (score 0):

Yash, I'm unable to comment on your answer, so I'm posting another one.

Solution: 
You need to check button text before clicking,

```
if btn.text == 'Follow':
    #Code to click button
```